Customizing Amasty Checkout: Conditional Display of Order Comments Field
I'm working with the Amasty Checkout extension and I need some assistance. Specifically, I want to modify the order comments field to only be visible after the customer selects an option (e.g., a checkbox or radio button).
I would like the behavior to be as follows:
A checkbox appears in the checkout form.
When the checkbox is checked, a text area for the order comments becomes visible, allowing the customer to add their comments.
If the checkbox is unchecked, the text area remains hidden.
I’ve been trying to figure out how to implement this, but I’m not sure where to start. Has anyone had experience customizing this in the Amasty Checkout? Any guidance or code snippets would be greatly appreciated.
